# Batch set if command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want something like: if gas is lesser than 10 set `linha3=hello`

```
set Gas1=5

set /a Gas1-=15

if "%Gas1%" LSS "10" (

set linha3=Hello

)

echo !linha3!
```

Comment: Don't use quotes around your comparison. You also should not need to use delayed expansion to echo your variable.  It is outside the code block.

Comment: When using `!linha3!` you need to have issued a `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` before, or replace with the normal `%linha3%`

Comment: i already have the setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Answer (score 1):

Squashman gave you the answer in his comment, but you may not understand the significance of what he said.

The IF statement considers the quotes on either side of the comparison to be part of the string to be compared.

When IF sees a character within either string that is not numeric, then it does a string comparison instead of a numeric comparison, and quotes are not numeric.

Your logic is fixed by dropping the quotes

```
if %Gas1% LSS 10 (
```